Grafana hide variable values not in time range
I have Grafana setup with a Graphite data source. I want to display my Gatling performance metrics. And it works good overall. So the connection between gatling, graphite and grafana is done.
On my dashboard I have 2 variables: 
The Simulation variable is my simulation name. I just changed it to see whether both values are also present in Grafana. But I was running both my simulation runs sequentially, they have no time overlap. My assumption was, that I only see variable values of my currently selected time range. Here I had a time range selected that was only having data of the second simulation.
Is there a way to achive the variable value drop-down to only contain values relevant for my time frame? If no data is there, it can show NONE. I think I have seen this somewhere in the past...

Is Simulation a Custom (i.e. hardcoded) variable? Try changing it into a query one where you can take proper account of time etc.

it's a query.
User is: "gatling."
Simulation is: "gatling.$User."
